# Cut off the first two lines

Tags: text-processing, cut, text-formatting

I'd like to retrive a list excluding the first 2 lines

```
$ pip list
Package                            Version  
---------------------------------- ---------
alabaster                          0.7.10   
anaconda-client                    1.6.9    
anaconda-navigator                 1.7.0    
anaconda-project                   0.8.2    
appnope                            0.1.0    
appscript                          1.0.1    
asn1crypto                         0.24.0   
astroid                            1.6.1    
astropy                            2.0.3    
attrs                              17.4.0
```

How to cut off the first two line like:

```
pip list | cut line=2
```

Comment: `awk 'NR>2' file`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply with the `sed` command:

```
pip list | sed '1,2d'
```

Explanation: The `sed` command deletes (`d`) lines in the range 1 to 2 (and outputs everything else).

Or `awk`:

```
pip list | awk 'NR > 2'
```

Explanation: The `awk` program outputs everything on line 3 onwards.

`awk` would be particularly useful if you are planning to do further parsing of that output, such as extracting only the package names:

```
pip list | awk 'NR > 2 { print $1 }'
```

---

The `cut` command, that you mention in the question (disregarding that the semantics used is wrong), does not cut *lines*.  Well, it does, but it cuts *fields* out of lines.

Comment: Actually, with GNU `cut`, one can do `seq 20 | cut -d$'\n' -f3-`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's treating the whole file as a `\n`-delimited set of fields on a single line, so in a sense it's still cutting fields out of a line, but yes.

Comment: An advantage of using `tail`, beside the fact that it's going to be more efficient as it's the simple tool designed to that task is that with most implementations including non-GNU ones, it's going to work even on non-text input (like with very long lines, with NULs or sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters...), while several `sed` or `awk` implementations would choke on those.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The only reason I did not mention tail was that it is already mentioned in another answer.

Comment: Yes, I don't doubt that. Those comments were just additional notes, not a critique to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Simply with **`tail`** command:

```
pip list | tail -n+3 -
```

- from `tail` signature `tail [OPTION]... [FILE]...` - when `FILE` is `-`, read standard input
- `-n, --lines=[+]NUM` - output the last `NUM` lines, instead of the last 10; or use `-n +NUM` to output starting with line `NUM`